# Как применить media query внутри конкретного класса?

Tags: html, css, css3

Я хочу перерисовать дизайн боковой панели. В данный момент у меня ширина панели 300 пикселей. Я хочу перерисовать элементы внутри панели в зависимости от ширины панели. Т.Е. когда панель стала шириной в 75 пикселей мне нужно всем классам внутри панели определить другой css

Как это сделать? Я нашел ссылку на [статью](http://lesscss.org/features/#features-overview-feature-nested-directives-and-bubbling), но не совсем понял это доп плагин или это реальное решение?

Comment: то что в статье - это less, язык стиля, который компилируеться в цсс. В обычном цсс нужно в медиа блоки засунуть классы

Comment: Я немного переписал свой вопрос что бы было более понятно. Мне необходимо в медиа запросах прописать новые классы с css, но мне нужно что бы медиа запросы проверяли не ширину экрана, а ширину определенного класса, т.е. контейнера боковой панели

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В css если я не ошибаюсь никак но через js можно.

```js
function resize(e) {
  $(".block").width(e.target.value);
  if($(".block").width() < 33) {
    $(".block").css('background', 'red');
  } else if ($(".block").width() < 66) {
    $(".block").css('background', 'orange');
  } else {
    $(".block").css('background', 'green');
  }
}
```

```css
.block {
height:50px;
width:50px;
background:orange;
transition:1s background;
}
.parent{
width:100px;
border:1px solid black;
position:relative;
}
.parent:after {
content:'';
width:10px;
height:20px;
border:1px solid black;
position:absolute;

left:100%;
top:50%;
transform:translate(0, -50%);
}
input[type="range"] {
width:100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
<div class="block"></div>
</div>
<input type="range" oninput="resize(event)">
```

Comment: Спасибо! буду тогда через js. Об этом решение я тоже знаю но думал возможно есть какой то способ через css

Answer (score 0):

Конечно можно:
.bar { Width: 300px;}
@media all and (max-width: 600px) {  .bar {Width: 150px;}}

http://htmlbook.ru/css/value/media

Comment: не то, это размер экрана, а ему нужен размер блока